# How to set buttons with dynamic ID's clickable jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have form that goes like this:

```
<?php foreach($userID as id):?>

<input type="button" id="ok_<?php echo id?>" value="ok" />
<input type="button" id="cancel_<?php echo id?>" value="cancel" />

<?php endforeach;?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//how do i set the click events of these buttons, assuming i have 3 sets of the of the ok and cancel buttons.

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select the buttons by their value attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('[value="ok"]').on('click', function(ev) {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });

});
```

Comment: it's `this.id`, or `$(this).attr('id')` - **not** `this.attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delegate` and attach only 1 handler for each of the type of buttons. It will take care of any number of buttons click event. Try this.

```
$(document).delegate('input[id=^"ok_"]', 'click', function(){
      //Write code here
}).delegate('input[id=^"cancel_"]', 'click', function(){
      //Write code here
});
```

`.delegate()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

If you are using jQuery ver 1.7+ then you can use `on` with is similar to delegate except for the first 2 arguments interchanged.

```
$(document).delegate('click', 'input[id=^"ok_"]', function(){
      //Write code here
}).delegate('click', 'input[id=^"cancel_"]', function(){
      //Write code here
});
```

Note: In the above code it is always better to provide a container which will contain those elements instead of specifying `document` to reduce the scope.

Comment: `.delegate` is obsolete in jQuery 1.7+

Comment: @Alnitak - Added `on` implementation also in case OP is using latest jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[id*=ok_]').bind('click', function(e){
            console.log($(this));
        });
        $('input[id*=cancel_]').bind('click', function(e){
            console.log($(this));
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not set  css classes to them. then attach the event to the class.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is the better assign one class to your buttons then give the event

```
<?php foreach($userID as id):?>
<input class="event" type="button" id="ok_<?php echo id?>" value="ok" />
<input class="event" type="button" id="cancel_<?php echo id?>" value="cancel" />

<?php endforeach;?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".event").click(function() {
           // click event code
     });  

});
</script>
```